# If I use a real building in a real city could I be liable for some sort of lawsuit?

Tags: fiction, legal

I want to use a real building (skyscraper) in a real city that will be the subject of a terrorist attack and partially brought down with disastrous effect on the surrounding neighborhood.  Good idea or bad?  Could I be liable?  How can I avoid liability?

Comment: @Sciborg I read a few of the answers on that post, and I didn't really see any relating to the destruction of the properties, which could be different. I think the name of this question should be edited to reference the destruction aspect specifically (I'm newer to the site than you though, so I'm not really sure)

Comment: @BumpoBiddleton I think that's absolutely a valid point, OP if you were to edit the question a bit to emphasize that aspect it would be sufficiently different to not be a duplicate. I don't want to do it myself as I don't want to guess wrong about your authorial intent.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem as long as you are not defaming the building, it's owners, or management (e.g. "the building collapsed due to poor design and years of neglect making it unsafe anyways).